# How does ghc resolve paths for libraries ?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-pkg

I'm starting to to use haskell with nixpkgs. From [the official guide to nixpkgs](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#how-to-install-a-compiler-with-libraries) I read:

> GHC expects to find all installed libraries inside of its own lib directory.

As it is stated it seems that it is saying that *ghc* require all the library to be installed in the same path.

I thought that ghc was able to find out the path of libraries by looking at packages database configured through ghc-pkg.
If this is the case, it should be possible to put libraries under different 
directories in the filesystem and configuring the package-db to resolve these different paths. 
But this would contradict what said in the above mentioned link, so what am I not getting?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC has several command line options which allow you to manipulate how it searches for packages:

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#idp46686514389712

In short, GHC allows you to specify a stack of of package directories (like a package db search path) so you can have it access libraries in different directories.

Comment: So basically my understanding was correct and I have misinterpreted what said in the link above?

Comment: Yes - your understanding is correct. That paragraph presents a simplified view of package databases, and its purpose is to motivate the need for the `ghcWithPackages` function presented in the next paragraph. Moreover, even though the statement "GHC’s store path is immutable once it’s built" is not technically true, nix would never modify the system package-db. Being "functional" it would create another package-db to layer on top of the system-db, and in that sense the statement is true.